# Проблемка с ссылками

Tags: javascript, php, link, site

В общем, пишу небольшой сайт. Главное меню сайта находится в отдельном файле. То есть, я подключаю его везде где мне нужно.
Загвоздка в том, что в этом отдельном файле прописаны ссылки на другие страницы относительно текущей, т.е главной страницы.

Чтобы было понятней: Допустим этот отдельный файл с меню выглядит так (PHP):

```
$name="Главная";
$href="directory/subdirectory";
echo '<a href="$href">$name</a>';
```

Теперь если я подключу файл меню например к файлу по адресу `directory/subdirectory/file.php`, то получается все ссылки в меню в нём будут вести в `directory/subdirectory`.
Т.е., фактически ссылки будут вести к `directory/subdirectory/directory/subdirectory` и получается что ссылки уже битые, и правильными они будут только если меню будет подключено к главной странице.

Как поступить в этом случае? Для каждой страницы присваивать свой адрес ссылкам относительно текущей страницы? С таким же успехом я могу и не делать отдельной страницы с меню, а просто на каждой странице заново переписывать меню.

Надеюсь я достаточно понятно обьяснил.

Comment: почитать про абсолютные пути

Comment: Используйте абсолютные пути по типу "https://mysite.ru/directory/subdirectory/file.php" .
Если работаете на локалке , то можете сделать через протокол не https , а через file:///

Comment: по идее Вы забыли слеш в начале пути $href="/directory/subdirectory";

Comment: @HTOHOT никакого  mysite.ru в путях быть не должно. Не говоря уже про file:///.

Comment: @4isto, вот правильно, это решение проблемы. Правда позже сам нашёл ответ, но вопрос удалять не буду. Мало ли, вдруг кому-то ещё пригодиться. Щас решение дабавлю в вопрос

Comment: Добавь решение в качестве ответа, и отметь ответ принятым (так можно делать, и более того - это поощряется, когда вопрос и ответ полезны).

Comment: @yar85 если только вопрос не является дубликатом

Comment: @Ипатьев, даже если вопрос будет закрыт дубликатом - он все равно будет искаться, и может принести пользу. Насколько знаю, при наличии ответов оцененных полезными, закрытие влияет только на (не)возможность добавлять новые ответы. А вопросов с одной и той же проблемой но разными ситуациями, тут существует достаточно много - такая практика не вызывает отторжения у сообщества. В конце концов, за 14 часов вопрос не получил минусов и голосов за закрытие, а раз автор решил поделиться своим решением, в этом действии нет ничего предосудительного...

Comment: @yar85 если вопрос закрыт как дубль без ответа, то он не будет "искаться". Но вообще-то вы потеряли нить своих рассуждений. Вопрос был о том, какие ответы поощряются, а какие нет. Ответы на вопросы-дубликаты правилами не поощряются.

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо за токсичность по отношению к новичку, неловко прикрытую однобоким толкованием правил (с игнорированием основной цели stackoverflow). Надеюсь, такая самореализация за счет других, приносит тебе больше пользы чем этому сайту. Если так беспокоишься о дубликатах, то в соответствии с правилами тебе следовало бы начать с указания связанного вопроса, дубликатом которого является этот.

Comment: @yar85 вас все время уносит куда-то в сторону. Какие-то новички, какая-то токсичность, постоянные отсылки к конкретному вопросу. Я всего лишь написал очевидное дополнение к общему правилу, которое вы привели выше. Не вижу, с чем тут можно спорить.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а причины для полемики - видишь? :] Мне на самом деле тоже интересно, с чем ты тут пытаешься столь желчно спорить. Ведь если внимательнее посмотреть выше, то понесло тут именно тебя (втиснуться чтобы написать в комментариях то, чему там **вообще не место**: свои ненужные характеристики чужим рассуждениям), т.к. в моем комменте вполне четко было обозначено: _«при наличии ответов оцененных полезными»_. Твое "очевидное дополнение" в данном случае просто неадекватно объекту дополнения, т.к. оно игнорирует контекст и смысл написанного... где речь шла и об этом вопросе, в том числе.

Comment: @yar85 я как раз и пишу что причин для полемики не вижу. Если не высасывать из пальца допущения типа "неадекватно объекту дополнения" то и спорить не о чем.

Comment: @Ипатьев, хорошо что не видишь - теперь желательно сделать следующий шаг, пересмотрев свои действия. Во-первых, лучше воздерживаться от написания комментариев с неконструктивным/неуместным содержанием. Во-вторых, (в качестве пояснения к замечанию сделанному ранее), отсылки к общим положениям правил надо подкреплять не "вбросами", а ссылками - так гораздо полезнее. В-третьих, по поводу однозначности _«ответы на дубликаты не поощряются»_: прошу тебя обратить внимание на смысл 1го параграфа в статье [Почему некоторые вопросы отмечаются как дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: @Ипатьев ну и, прошу пересмотреть минус ответу, если он твой - потому что ответ показывает стремление автора поделиться с сообществом, и это действие совсем не заслуживает осуждения (даже если есть претензии к качеству вопроса)... То есть, я согласен с тем что вопрос может восприниматься некачественным, но оценка вопроса не должна влиять на оценку ответа, или на отношение к участнику лично. Нам вообще предписывается делать поблажки новичкам. Как минимум, хорошо бы воздержаться от "немых минусов": если ставить минус, то в первый раз объяснить его (т.к. новички не всегда понимают свои ошибки).

Comment: @yar85 "следующий шаг" - это будет продолжение полемики. А я, как уже не раз отмечал, не вижу здесь повода для дискуссий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае необходимо использовать путь относительно корня сайта, путём добавления слеша в начале ссылки, т.е не `<a href="folder/file.php">Link</a>` а `<a href="/folder/file.php">Link</a>`

В этом случае ссылки не будут "ломаться" при подключении файла с меню к другим страницам, а будут ввести отсчёт относительно корня сайта, независимо от того, куда был подключён файл с меню